# Multiple POST requests from same client, with different IP-numbers

Tags: php, apache, http, proxy, http-proxy

I have an online store running on PHP/Apache. When one of our clients is trying to submit an order, several orders are created. Looking in the HTTP logs, I can see that the client has made multiple POST requests in the checkout page, with a new IP number each time but with the same user-agent.

All but one of the IPs seem to be from a proxy called ScanSafe. They do include the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header which contains the user's own IP.

The same problem is occuring on other pages. I can see that GET and POST requests are sometimes made once (with a random IP - either one of the proxy IPs or the client's IP) and sometimes multiple times.

I could potentially block the additional requests. But how do I know which HTTP response the client's browser will process - the first or the last? If the last response is processed, then how can I block the first request? Again, the IP of the request is sometimes the client's, sometimes the proxy's.

I have never before heard of ScanSafe but the client insists it's a good product with "130 000 users".

Comment: Truls, what is your exact problem with the multiple IP adresses? Do you link orders to IP adresses? The use of ScanSafe is quite normal indeed, for some people want to browse in more privacy then others. If you match order to IP, check if HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR is present. If so, that is your client's IP address. But that is no guarantee. Most likely you do not want to match IP to order anymore. Especially with new privacy laws

Comment: We don't match IP to orders. The problem is that several orders are created, because we recieve several POST requests to the script which creates the order. And I don't know which of them I should block. I guess it could be solved with a cookie - only create one order from a randomly created cookie value from the cart. But I still need to send a HTTP response to the request that created the order, so which request should I pick? They are all sending the same cookie package, and the same user-agent.

Comment: If they are all sending the same cookie package, they should also have the same PHP session cookie. Thus linking it to the same user session. The fact that your system creates multiple orders might be the error then. Or the user might be submitting multiple times. Not sure how you can catch that error. I would need more specific info to help you out on this one bro. Maybe someone else can help you

Comment: Yes, I could use the session value to stop multiple orders from being created. But I still need to send a http response to the request which the client's browser will actually proces. Such as a 301 to the payment processor. I don't want all of the requests to carry on creating invoices/transaction and such.

Comment: Each request corresponds to a client's action. ScanSafe does not create multiple requests to ensure anonymous surfing.  Each request therefor could/should be answered. Restricting from my point of view should be a decision made by you and my best guess would be 1 per session per minute or so or even one active order process at any time